# Use nuget packages in script task

Tags: c#, ssis, etl, script-task

I am trying to make [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication) and its dependencies work with SSIS script task. How do I resolve assembly reference errors?

[image]

```cs
static ScriptMain()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
}

static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{

    if (args.Name.Contains("Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication"))
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Azure\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.1.6.2\lib\net472\Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.dll");
    }

    if (args.Name.Contains("Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory"))
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Azure\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.5.2.9\lib\net45\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Nuget packages are not supported in SSIS script task/component. You need to download the assemblies manually from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/releases).

Next, you should add these assemblies to the Global cache assembly (GAC):

- [How to: Install an assembly into the global assembly cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac)
- [Use Visual C# to install an assembly into the Global Assembly Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/general/install-assembly-gac)

---

You can refer to the following article for more guidance:

- [Referencing Other Assemblies in Scripting Solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/referencing-other-assemblies-in-scripting-solutions?view=sql-server-ver15)